# Reading RSA keys from strings

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, rsa

I am trying to use RSA to decrypt some stuff using OpenSSL. I want to load a public key. 
The default function provided to do this is PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY() which requires a file descriptor.

I would like to embed the keys into the program as strings. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `d2i_RSA_PUBKEY` to load directly from a buffer containing binary DER format:

```
const unsigned char *p = key;
RSA *r = d2i_RSA_PUBKEY(NULL, &p, keylen);
```